# Shoiwng menu while hovering on table row in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am stuck in a scenario and scenario is that I have a table of product and I want to show menu of sub product's whenever I hover on a particular row-but not able to do it-Anyone please help-

Answer (score 0):

You can create a state variable with `useState` and use it to show the menu in sub-product.

For example,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function ShowLabelHover() {
  const [visibleMenu, setVisibleMenu] = useState({ display: "none" });
  const style = {
    border: "1px solid gray",
    width: 200,
    height: 50,
    padding: 10,
    margin: 100
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        style={style}
        onMouseEnter={(e) => {
          setVisibleMenu({ display: "block" });
        }}
        onMouseLeave={(e) => {
          setVisibleMenu({ display: "none" });
        }}
      >
        <label style={visibleMenu}>Here is some text!</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```